# Blender 2.79 not open properly

Tags: objects

[image]

I can't understand blender 2.79b open like this, I am trying to install again but the same problem

Comment: I am voting to close the question. No problem is described. No question is formed.

Comment: Hi, if you're referring to the layout of the Program window areas, it could be that you (or someone else) saved the default startup file with such layout. I see that the above layout is called "Blender", which is not a default one, iirc. Try to select a layout named "default", then under the 'file' menu, save your preferred startup file, or reset to "factory settings", then save as your startup file. Settings like this are maintained even if reinstalling (into windows user preferences)

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File** -> **Load Factory Settings**. It will reset to default layout.

[image]

When save this layout by **File** -> **Save Startup File**